# subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am having trouble with the following SQL Statement. I am getting back an error saying "ORA-01427:single-row subquery returns more than one row" and I'm not exactly sure how to fix the error. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you, Brad

```
select t.check_amount,
   t.check_amount_text,
   t.agency_no,
   t.branch_no,
   substr(t.payee_name,1,10),
   substr(t.payee_name,11),
   (select c.contact_primary_email 
    from contact c,
         contact_role cr,
         branch b
    where c.contact_id = cr.contact_id
          and cr.entity_id = b.branch_id
          and cr.contact_role_code = 'ACHCONTACT')

from CHECK_REGISTER t
where t.check_type = 'C' 
  and t.check_date > to_date('01/31/2014','mm/dd/yyyy')
and t.disbursement_fund_type = 'ACH'
```

Comment: You need some way to make that subquery return one row. Can't really tell you how to do that from here. Select Distinct might do it, Limit 1 would do it, if it were me I'd be running it by itself and try and tighten it up. Personally I'd change it to a join on the branch_id myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because you have a `select` statement where a single value is expected.  The `select` is returning more than one row, so Oracle reports an error.

In a query such as yours, this is usually because you need to *correlate* the inner subquery to the outer query.  My best guess is that this query wants the email address of the primary contact at the branch.  For this, the query would be:

```
   (select c.contact_primary_email 
    from contact c join
         contact_role cr
         on c.contact_id = cr.contact_id join
         branch b
         on cr.entity_id = b.branch_id
    where b.branch_no = t.branch_no and cr.contact_role_code = 'ACHCONTACT'
   ) as email
```

This postulates that the correlation condition on `branch_no`.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon!